# ASROCK Fatal1ty Motherboard X370: Memory support

Tags: memory

http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Professional%20Gaming/#Specification

I am somewhat bit lost on figuring out which memory that motherboard does support.

On one lines it say "- Supports DDR4 ***3200+(OC)***/2933(OC)/2667/2400/2133 ECC & non-ECC, un-buffered memory*"

I have a quick installation guide booklet that say the same thing about 3200+(OC).

Yet the following table only list MHZ up to 2667. I may be misreading the table.

I talked to the computer department manager at Fry's Electronic (local DIY store for PC). He said go for 3000 MHZ because that is the motherboard clock rate.

I went to G.SKill website RAM configurator it only shows support for 2133 MHZ to 2400 MHZ for x370 pro gaming MB.

So my question is the 3200 listed overclocked to THIS amount or by default at 3200 and can overclock above that?

Comment: By the way this question is off topic for this site, please ask on superuser.com for more informed answers (I answered your question anyway ;))

Comment: @E.Nunn Please don't do that. If you *know* a question is off-topic, answering it is not constructive.

Comment: How did this question get flagged as hardware support? I have not figured out which range of MHZ to buy for RAM. So... the answer was there is no constriction outside of DDR4.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Sorry, It won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard can run any of the listed RAM speeds, but the extra speed will not be utilised if you do not use Extreme Memory Profile (XMP), leaving your more expensive purchase of faster RAM a useless investment.

Due to this, If you are not thinking of modifying your BIOS settings, I would recommend choosing which ever speed of RAM is the least expensive in the range/brand you are looking at.

For example, Corsair Dominator Platinum 2400Mhz is actually more expensive p/gb than 3000Mhz, even though some of the customers of the 3000Mhz product won't use the XMP option, the price is better because uninformed PC enthusiasts buy more of the faster RAM, as it seems more beneficial.

The answer to your question is that the RAM is clocked at the speed listed, but to take advantage of that speed, you will need to enable the XMP option in your BIOS menu.

OC means that the memory controller on the motherboard is overclocked when using 2933 or faster RAM, such as the 3200Mhz products.

Comment: I am planning to get something like amd ryzen 1700x which comes with base clock rate of 3.4 Mhz. Which make it possible going by what you said to make full use of 3.2 Mhz ram. I am moving over from AM2 CPU 1075T. Thus ANY speed above 1333 Mhz (total 8 GB over 4 cards) is a nice upgrade at this rate. :)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work like that. The clock of the processor isn't directly linked to maximum supported clock speeds of the RAM. Some of the i7 list which clock up to 4.2 Ghz can only officially support 2400 Mhz RAM. Look on the manufacturers site for details. If you take a peek on ark.intel.com , it will show exactly that for high end processors such as the i7-4790k

Comment: Yeah I just realize that could be a problem after looking at this link. https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-1700x It say 2667 MHZ memory supports but there are some reviews that suggests going over that (also corresponding OC their cpu) saw huge improvement for Ryzen Zen line of CPU. Also most Ryzen CPU seem to support much higher memory speed than intel counterpart so.

Comment: By the way, AMD may have a higher memory speed support, but there is a reason why AMD CPUs are much cheaper than their Intel counterparts, because they can afford to put in more features, considering the AMD usage of more slower cores, compared to the expensive Intel usage of fewer, faster cores.

Comment: Here is a user who pushed 3200 MHZ (2x 8 GB) on a 1700 which is basically a slimmer version of 1700x. So the result could be reasonable similar better on 1700x. 16% boost in 1080 gaming. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G80uG3acg44 Most of this was 3 month ago.

Comment: My bad, I have just realised that a function called XMP in the BIOS makes it possible to utilise faster RAM speeds than the recommended CPU RAM supported speed without overclocking your CPU. I edited my answer accordingly.