# RAM recommendation

Tags: memory, compatibility

I am looking for a [2x8Go DDR3 RAM](https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_style_browse-bin_2?rh=n%3A340858031%2Cn%3A!340859031%2Cn%3A427941031%2Cn%3A430351031%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_two_browse-bin%3A4370880031%2Cp_n_style_browse-bin%3A199703031) below ~150€ based on this configuration:

- ASUS P8P67-M
- Intel Core i5-2500K
- GeForce GTX 980

From the motherboard specifications:

> Dual-Channel DDR3 2200(O.C.) / 2133(O.C.) / 1866(O.C.) / 1600(O.C.) / 1333 / 1066MHz

Does `O.C.` mean it will gracefully fallback to 1333MHz if not overclocked?

Should I pick the Kingston HyperX Fury HX313C9FBK2 DDR3 **1333MHz CL9** over HX318C10FBK2 DDR3 **1866MHz CL10** if compatible, or is there a more reliable manufacturer?

One thing I got from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/509824/which-ram-is-faster-1333-mhz-cl9-or-1600-mhz-cl10) to compare RAM let me think I should unless I plan to overclock:

```
1866 Mhz / CL10 = 186.6
1333 Mhz / CL10 = 133.3
1333 Mhz / CL9  = 148.1
```

Finally, is 2x8Go reasonable or should I aim higher to be safe, knowing that I will have four slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my [accepted answer here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7874/asrock-fatal1ty-motherboard-x370-memory-support) for an overview of XMP and OC in relation to memory.

This [Corsair Vengeance Pro DDR3](https://www.amazon.fr/Corsair-CMY16GX3M2A1600C9R-Vengeance-ordinateur-performante/dp/B00D5XAN06/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1503243259&sr=8-1&keywords=CMY16GX3M2A1600C9&th=1) memory is probably a good choice for you. It comes in varying colors, which are all roughly around 150 EUR, or the Red version, which is 130 EUR.

This is the RAM that I actually have in my personal machine, and I have never had any issues whatsoever.

However, if you are set on purchasing the HyperX brand, then take the faster RAM speeds incase you want to use the XMP functionality at a later date.

RAM is expensive at the moment so around 8GB per DIMM should be fine for future upgrades.